# Eclipse (Luna) Slowness

Tags: eclipse

I've recently "upgraded" from Indigo to Luna (Oracle OEPE installation). Note the quotations around the term upgraded.

Unfortunately, the thing is SLOW.

The project I work with is a maven multi-module project. A building workspace operation takes about 3-4 minutes, and Updating Navigator Content Viewer (whatever that is) can take even longer.

Plugins of note:
- Subclipse
- M2E
- JRebel

Any ideas on improving performance before the thing makes me psychotic?

Comment: This is killing me. It happens on any large project I open. Nothing I do so far seems to help.

Comment: Right now, I'm suspecting that the slowness is only occurring when my server is running. But, I switched over to Netbeans for the moment.

Comment: I had 4 projects open as a matter of convenience. So I closed 3 of them and now just open them as I need to. A pain but Luna is running better.

Comment: Out of the plugins you mentioned I only have M2E.

Answer (score 2):

I have just un-ticked everything under [**Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Java EE Integration**] and so far no "Updating Navigator Content Viewer" here!